# How to inject dependecies using Governator within TestNG test cases?

Tags: java, testng, guice, governator

I'm working on a test automation framework which use *TestNG*. I decided to use *Dependency Injection* pattern in order to implement more readable, reusable page objects and tests.

I've chosen *Google Guice* due to *TestNG* provides built-in support to inject test objects with *Guice Modules*. I only had to specify my *Guice Modules* as you can see at next code snippet:

```java
    @Guice(modules = CommModule.class)
    public class CommunicationTest {

        @Inject
        private Communication comms;

        @Test
        public void testSendMessage() {
            Assertions.assertThat(comms.sendMessage("Hello World!")).isTrue();
        }
    }
```

So far so good, although I'm going to need more advance DI features such as:

- Lifecycle management
- Configuration to field mapping
- Generic binding annotations

Therefore, I'd like to use [Netflix/Governator](https://github.com/Netflix/governator/wiki) since it enhance *Google Guice* with these features. In order to trigger *Governator* features I must create the `Injector` through it instead of *TestNG*. e.g:

```java
    Injector injector = LifecycleInjector.builder()
        .withModules(CommModules.class).build().createInjector();
```

And I'd like to do it mostly transparent as possible like *TestNG* does it.

I would like to know if:

- Is it possible to provide my own `Injector` instance to *TestNG* in order to reuse `@Guice` annotation approach ?
- Do you know any library for integrating *Governator* with *TestNG* ?

You can find in [here](https://github.com/eljaiek/test-automation-playground/tree/master/guice-playground) what I've done so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not possible until now. I have fixed this in the latest snapshot version of TestNG. It should be available in the upcoming version of TestNG (Any version greater than `7.0.0`)

The issue that I created to track this : https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2199

In a nutshell, you can do the following :

- Implement the interface `org.testng.IInjectorFactory`
- Plugin the fully qualified class name of the newly created implementation via the command line argument `-dependencyinjectorfactory`

Comment: Could it be possible to specify the implementation for `org.testng.IInjectorFactory` using *Java SPI*

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek - From an implementation perspective, yes it can be supported. But from semantics perspective, I think it won't be correct. Because if your test project depends on two other projects both of which inject their own `IInjectorFactory` variants, then TestNG would get confused as to which implementation to use because the _Java SPI_ aggregates all implementations and provides it to the user.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. I'm going to post an answer showing up 
what I've done so far to support *Governator Injector* in my projects, 
meanwhile a new *TestNG* version is released. 
Because I like how *Java SPI* helped me out to provide an abstraction layer for my projects. 
It will be great if you can take a look to it in your free time. 
I'll appreciate your feedback.

Comment: How do I make this work when running via maven surefire plugin? I tried to add <property><name>dependencyinjectorfactory</name><value>my.injectorfactory.fqcn</value></property> to the properties of maven surefire plugin, but it didn't work. I also tried running "mvn test -Ddependencyinjectorfactory=my.injectorfactory.fqcn" but it didn't work either. I could only make it work when using intelliJ idea's runner

Comment: @Ubeogesh Is `fqcn` a class or a package name ?

Comment: @EduardoEljaiek factory's fully qualified **class** name

Answer (score 1):

Since [Allow user to provide DI Injector](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2199) *TestNG* feature is going to be present in versions greater than `7.0.0`. I implemented a solution using *TestNG* version `7.0.0` listeners.

Firstly, I created a module called [autopilot-testng-runner](https://github.com/eljaiek/autopilot/tree/master/autopilot-testng-runner) with the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.governator</groupId>
        <artifactId>governator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This module contains the artifacts described at next:

- [@AutopilotTest](https://github.com/eljaiek/autopilot/blob/master/autopilot-testng-runner/src/main/java/com/github/eljaiek/autopilot/testng/AutopilotTest.java): Custom annotation for declaring which *Guice* modules must be used for creating the `Injector` with `LifecycleInjector.builder()`. I couldn't reuse `@Guice` annotation due to *TestNG* also will create its Injector and declared dependencies will be created twice.
- [AutopilotSuiteListener](https://github.com/eljaiek/autopilot/blob/master/autopilot-testng-runner/src/main/java/com/github/eljaiek/autopilot/testng/AutopilotSuiteListener.java): Implementation of `ISuiteListener` for creating the parent `Injector`, *Governator's* `LifecycleManager` instance and bind configuration properties before Suite starts. Therefore each *Suite* is going to have a parent `Injector` built with *Governator* and a life-cycle manager.
- [AutopilotTestListener](https://github.com/eljaiek/autopilot/blob/master/autopilot-testng-runner/src/main/java/com/github/eljaiek/autopilot/testng/AutopilotTestListener.java): `ITestListener` implementation in charge of injecting dependencies in the running test case.
- [META-INF/services/org.testng.ITestNGListener](https://github.com/eljaiek/autopilot/blob/master/autopilot-testng-runner/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.testng.ITestNGListener): Service provider configuration file containing the fully qualified names of both `ITestNGListener` implementations.

Then, I added `autopilot-testng-runner` as a maven dependency in my [project](https://github.com/eljaiek/test-automation-playground/tree/master/guice-playground)

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.eljaiek.playground</groupId>
        <artifactId>autopilot-testng-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And finally, I replaced `@Guice` annotation with `@AutopilotTest`

```java
    @AutopilotTest(modules = CommModule.class)
    public class CommunicationTest {

        @Inject
        private Communication comms;

        @Test
        public void testSendMessage() {
            Assertions.assertThat(comms.sendMessage("Hello World!")).isTrue();
        }
    }
```